# Using the Disk graphics primitive

Tags: regions, geometry

Please be kind enough to give me some indication on how to use the `Disk` graphics primitive in any of these cases:

[image]

I want to calculate the area and perimeter of the shaded portions.

I have looked for something that tells me how to do it, but I can't find anything acceptable. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 6):

You can specify the quarter disks using the three-argument form of `Disk`.

For the first picture:

```
a = 1;
d1 = Disk[{0, 0}, a, {0, Pi/2}];
d2 = Disk[{a, 0}, a, {Pi/2, Pi}];
d3 = Disk[{0, a}, a, {-Pi/2, 0}];

ri = RegionIntersection[d1, d2, d3];
Through[{Perimeter, N @* Area} @ ri]
```

> {2.61799, 0.442972}

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], Opacity[.25], Orange, d1, Blue, d2, Green, d3,  
 RegionPlot[ri, PlotStyle -> Red][[1]]}]
```

[image]

A simpler alternative is to take the intersections of full disks with `Rectangle[{0, 0}, {a, a}]`:

```
d1b = RegionIntersection[Rectangle[{0,0}, {a,a}], Disk[{0,0}, a]];
d2b = RegionIntersection[Rectangle[{0,0}, {a,a}], Disk[{a,0}, a]];
d3b = RegionIntersection[Rectangle[{0,0}, {a,a}], Disk[{0,a}, a]];

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], Opacity[.25], Orange, d1b, Blue, d2b, Green, d3b,  
 RegionPlot[ri, PlotStyle -> Red][[1]]}]
```

> same picture

For the second picture:

```
d4b = RegionIntersection[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {a, a}], Disk[{a, a}, a]];
ru = RegionUnion[RegionIntersection[d1b, d4b], RegionIntersection[d2b, d3b]];
rc = RegionDifference[Rectangle[], ru];

Through[{Perimeter, N @* Area} @ rc]
```

> {8.18879, 0.173554}

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], Red, Rectangle[], 
  RegionPlot[ru, PlotStyle -> White][[1]], 
  Opacity[.05], White, d1b, d2b, d3b, d4b}]
```

[image]

Similarly, for the third picture:

```
rd = RegionDifference[ Disk[{a, a}/2, a/2], d2b];
Through[{Perimeter, N @* Area} @ rd]
```

> {2.18282, 0.146381}

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], White, Rectangle[], Opacity[.25], Blue, d2b,
   Orange, Disk[{a, a}/2, a/2], 
   RegionPlot[rd, PlotStyle -> Red, BoundaryStyle -> None][[1]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, @kglr ,  for the third image I get   http://img.fenixzone.net/i/CDrVGNz.png

why is this happening to me in my matthematca (ver 11.3)

Comment: @zeros, I don't have access to v11.3. Do you still get the circle if you remove `RegionPlot[rd, PlotStyle -> Red, BoundaryStyle -> None][[1]]`?

Comment: if I  remove RegionPlot[rd, PlotStyle -> Red, BoundaryStyle -> None][[1]] ,nothing appears

Comment: I still have no clear use of the command, you can show me with those 2 axes a little more how to work with disk    https://ibb.co/hMrH6K5, THANKS

Comment: @zeros, with the link in your comment i get a "malicious content" warning from my virus protection app.

Comment: sorry , https://postimg.cc/F1XZSYQR   ,I still have no clear use of the command, you can show me with those 2 examples a little more how to work with the primitiva "  disk", thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here is an alternative of 
[the previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/206454/34008) 
that *might* give you the plots in your question (after a sufficient number of experiments.)

```
Clear[RandomDisk]
RandomDisk[] := {Opacity[RandomChoice[Range[0, 1, 0.25]]], 
   FaceForm[RandomChoice[{None, Pink, Gray, LightBlue}]], 
   EdgeForm[Black], 
   Disk[RandomChoice[
     Append[Flatten[Outer[List, {0, 1}, {0, 1}], 1], {0.5, 0.5}]], 
    RandomChoice[{0.5, 1}]]};

Clear[RandomRectangle]
RandomRectangle[] := {EdgeForm[
   RandomChoice[{None, Black, Blue, Red, Gray, Orange, LightBlue}]], 
  FaceForm[None], Rectangle[]}

Multicolumn[
 Table[Graphics[{Flatten[Table[RandomDisk[], RandomChoice[Range[4]]], 
     1], RandomRectangle[]}, Frame -> True, PlotRangeClipping -> True,
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}], 16], 4]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

For the first image

```
reg[1, a_] = Disk[{0, 0}, a, {0, Pi/2}];
reg[2, a_] = Disk[{a, 0}, a, {Pi/2, Pi}];
reg[3, a_] = Disk[{0, a}, a, {-Pi/2, 0}];
reg[4, a_] = RegionIntersection[reg[1, a], reg[2, a], reg[3, a]];

Show[
 Graphics[{
   EdgeForm[Black],
   Lighter[Blue, 0.6],
   Opacity[0.75],
   reg[1, 1], reg[2, 1], reg[3, 1]}],
 Region[reg[4, 1],
  BaseStyle -> Opacity[0.5, Blue]]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** The gap at the lower-left corner can be filled by using [`DiscretizeRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion.html)

```
Graphics[{
  EdgeForm[Black],
  Lighter[Blue, 0.6],
  Opacity[0.75],
  reg[1, 1], reg[2, 1], reg[3, 1],
  DiscretizeRegion[reg[4, 1],
   MeshCellStyle -> Opacity[0.5, Blue],
   MaxCellMeasure -> 1]}]
```

[image]

The area is proportional to `a^2`

```
And @@ Table[
  Area[reg[4, a]] == a^2*Area[reg[4, 1]],
  {a, 1, 10}]

(* True *)

area1 = a^2*Area[reg[4, 1]]

(* 1/12 a^2 (-6 Sqrt[3] + 5 π) *)

area1 // N

(* 0.442972 a^2 *)

Perimeter[reg[4, 1]]

(* 2.61799 *)
```

For the second image

```
reg[5, a_] = Disk[{a, a}, a, {Pi, 3 Pi/2}]; reg[6, a_] = 
 RegionUnion[
  BooleanRegion[#1 && #2 && ! #3 && ! #4 &, #] & /@
   {{reg[1, a], reg[2, a],
      reg[3, a], reg[5, a]},
    {reg[2, a], reg[5, a], reg[1, a], reg[3, a]},
    {reg[1, a], reg[3, a], reg[2, a], reg[5, a]},
    {reg[3, a], reg[5, a], reg[1, a], reg[2, a]}}];

Show[
 Graphics[{
   EdgeForm[Black],
   White, Opacity[0.25],
   reg[1, 1], reg[2, 1], reg[3, 1], reg[5, 1]}],
 Region[reg[6, 1], BaseStyle -> LightGray],
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

The area is proportional to `a^2`

```
And @@ Table[
  Area[reg[6, a]] == a^2*Area[reg[6, 1]],
  {a, 1, 10}]

(* True *)

area2 = a^2*Area[reg[6, 1]] // Simplify

(* -(1/3) a^2 (3 (-4 + Sqrt[3]) + 2 π) *)

area2 // N

(* 0.173554 a^2 *)

Perimeter[reg[6, 1]]

(* 7.11792 *)
```

This number for the perimeter is too low since each of the four subregions has a perimeter that must exceed `2`. Looking at 4 times the perimeter of a subregion

```
reg[6 sr, a_] = BooleanRegion[#1 && #2 && ! #3 && ! #4 &,
   {reg[1, a], reg[2, a], reg[3, a], reg[5, a]}];

4*Perimeter[reg[6 sr, 1]]

(* 8.18879 *)
```

For the last image

```
reg[7, a_] = Disk[{a/2, a/2}, a/2];

reg[8, a_] = BooleanRegion[#1 && ! #2 &, {reg[7, a], reg[2, a]}];

Show[
 Graphics[{
   EdgeForm[Black],
   White, Opacity[0.25],
   Rectangle[{0, 0}],
   reg[2, 1], reg[7, 1]}],
 Region[reg[8, 1], BaseStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

The area is proportional to `a^2`

```
And @@ Table[
  Area[reg[8, a]] == a^2*Area[reg[8, 1]] // Simplify,
  {a, 1, 10}]

(* True *)

area3 = a^2*Area[reg[8, 1]] //
   TrigToExp // FullSimplify

(* 1/8 a^2 (Sqrt[7] + π - ArcCot[3/Sqrt[7]] - 4 ArcTan[(5 Sqrt[7])/9]) *)

area3 // N

(* 0.146381 a^2 *)

Perimeter[reg[8, 1]]

(* 2.18282 *)
```

Comment: a doubt the drawings do not come out exact, they leave me incomplete, why is this?    http://img.fenixzone.net/i/nlD72cz.png

Comment: In the first image use of `DiscretizeRegion` fills the gap. I cannot reproduce any gaps in the third image. Recommend that you try using `DiscretizeRegion` there as well.